# node.js write mongoDB collection to file using Streams?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream, node-mongodb-native, fs

I'm playing around with node.js and [streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) trying to dump an entire mongoDB collection to a file but it isn't working. I suspect it has something to do with old style streams and 0.10 streams but I could be wrong.

The code below can also be found here: [github.com](https://github.com/nickpoorman/mongodb-collection-dump/blob/master/example/tofile.js)

`mongodb-collection-dump` is in that repo as well.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dump = require('mongodb-collection-dump');

var collectionDumpFile = '/tmp/collection-dump.json';

var f = fs.createWriteStream(collectionDumpFile);

f.on('open', function() {
  var d = dump('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test_db', 'testcollection', f);
});
d.on('end', function(){
  console.log("done in write");
});

d.on('error', function(err){
  console.log("there was an error");
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/ with json parameter...?

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't do anything. And while I could use mongoexport I would rather understand why I can't simply pipe the mongo stream to the fs stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mongodump` or `mongoexport` in order to create dumps of mongodb.

[`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) is better for backing up and stores not just data, but a lot of meta data about the collections, like indexes. As well you can call it to specific database (-d) as well as collection (-c).

To do it from node.js, use [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).